# Can a Microsoft Word Web Add-In share ribbon customizations with a VSTO Add-In?

Tags: ms-office, vsto, office-js, office-addins

I have successfully made Word VBA and VSTO Add-Ins share ribbon customizations in the past using code like this:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns:nsMvSample="Sample Namespace">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idQ="nsMvSample:TabAddIns" label="Sample Tab">
        <group idQ="nsMvSample:MyGroup" label="Sample Group">
          <button id="NewDocument" label="New Document" imageMso="FileNew" size="large" onAction="NewDocument_Click" supertip="Opens the Select Template dialog to create a new document."/>
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

I'm currently getting to know the newer Office Web Add-Ins. I'd like to slowly introduce them into my solution by moving commands one at a time from VSTO to Office Javascript.

Can a VSTO Add-In share ribbon customisations with the newer Office Web Add-Ins?
Can I use the same idQ syntax? If so, how do I setup the namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not. Office Web Add-ins use an [entirely different mechanism](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/design/add-in-commands) for defining commands in the ribbon. They support a more constrained set of requirements and controls (buttons and drop-down buttons).